# Ada pass array of records to c function

Tags: c, ada, gnat

I know that a similar question has already been posted, but its solution doesn't work for me. In my spec file I have the code:

```
type Colour_Component is mod 256;

type Colour is
    record
        A, R, G, B : Colour_Component;
    end record;

type Raw_Image_Data is array (Interfaces.C.int range <>) of Colour;

type Raw_Image is access all Raw_Image_Data;
pragma Convention (C, Raw_Image);
```

Then I try to interface with a C function:

```
function C_SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom (
    Pixels : Raw_Image;
    Width : int;
    Height : int;
    Depth : int;
    Pitch : int;
    Rmask : Unsigned_32;
    Gmask : Unsigned_32;
    Bmask : Unsigned_32;
    Amask : Unsigned_32)
    return System.Address;
pragma Import (C, C_SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom, "SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom");
```

But when I try to compile it I get a warning:

```
warning: type of "C_SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom.Pixels" does not correspond to C pointer
warning: this access type does not correspond to C pointer
```

Since I have my compiler flags set to treat warnings as errors this doesn't compile. Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing structure from C to Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227946/passing-structure-from-c-to-ada)

Comment: You might do better with Ada generic C-like pointers: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-3-2.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that the warning is worth taking seriously because an Ada access type referring to an array isn't certain to be pointing to the first array element.  Ada array representations aren't constrained to be the same as C. The access type may be pointing to a dope vector. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ada arrays come in two flavours, constrained and unconstrained arrays. C arrays are constrained (newer C standards also have dynamically sized arrays), but if you pass C arrays around function calls you either terminate them with a zero element or with a separate length parameter.

Anyway, you declared your parameter `Raw_Image` as an unconstrained array. There is no counterpart in C. You can only pass constrained arrays from or to C.

I think you have two options: (1) use address to access conversion or (2) use the binding generator `-fdump-ada-spec`

(1) declare your first parameter as of type `System.Address` and use the package [System.Address_To_Access_Conversions](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-13-7-2.html)

(2) The easiest way is to use the gcc switch -fdump-ada-spec on a C header. [See Generating Ada Bindings for C and C++ headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gnat_ugn/Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers.html#Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers)

Comment: This is the best solution. I got away with an access to the first element and the generic pointer package. The only issue with fdump... Is that the function in question takes a void pointer, so it generates a system.address iirc.